# How do I save only specific lines of text from a URL to a txt file using python?

Tags: python, url, split, range

So far, I've used the range function which works when I simply print the lines imported from the URL but when I try to save them to a txt file it only saves line 5 (or whatever the last number of the range is).

```
target_url="random URL"
request = requests.get(target_url)
text=request.text
lines=text.split("\n")
for i in range(1, 5):
    savefile = open('c:/Users/ghostsIIV/Desktop/examplefile.txt', 'w')
    savefile.write(lines[i])
savefile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite your file on every iteration, wiping out the previous information:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    savefile = open('c:/Users/ghostsIIV/Desktop/examplefile.txt', 'w')
    savefile.write(lines[i])
savefile.close()
```

If  you want to write five lines, then just leave the file open as you accumulate data:

```
savefile = open('c:/Users/ghostsIIV/Desktop/examplefile.txt', 'w')
for i in range(1, 5):
    savefile.write(lines[i])
savefile.close()
```

This is also a good time to learn `a` (append) mode.  Repeat your tutorial on Python files for that information.

Even shorter, open the file and write the four lines you want:

```
with open('c:/Users/ghostsIIV/Desktop/examplefile.txt', 'w') as savefile:
    savefile.write('\n'.join(lines[1:5])
```

`with` closes the file when you exit the block.